# How to update data in jQWidgets jqxtreegrid on keydown in filter bar?

Tags: angularjs, jqwidget, jqxtreegrid

How to update jqxtreegrid when I am typing something in filter bar? Currently, it requires us to click on search icon or to hit enter.